# Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal

Tags: excel, database, vba, database-connection, ado

The code below is not working on this stored procedure. It works on queries, and another stored procedure.

It will not debug.print the values for this stored procedure, and is returning an error "Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal"

```
Dim x As ADODB.Connection
Set x = New ADODB.Connection

x.ConnectionString = "Provider=a;Server=b;Database=c;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
x.Open

Dim y As ADODB.Recordset
Set y = New ADODB.Recordset
x.CommandTimeout = 0

Set y = x.Execute("exec SP_storedprocedure 0")
Debug.Print y(0), y(1), y(2), y(3)**--the problem is here**

y.Close
Set y = Nothing
x.Close
Set x = Nothing
```

Comment: Add a Watch on `y` and do some debugging. The eror message maybe indicates that your recordset doesn't have at least 4 fields...

Comment: What is the value of y.Fields.Count when it gets to the debug line??

Comment: @MarkBalhoff zero.  it should be 10...

Comment: Then it sounds to me like the problem is in the stored procedure and not this code.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff the stored procedure works fine in SSMS.  i have also tested another parameterized stored procedure that works..

Comment: And this stored procedure internally returns a table in the same fashion as "another stored procedure" that you tested?

Comment: @TimWilliams what is a watch, and how do I add it?

Comment: A watch displays the value of a formula or an expression while you debug your code. It can also be set to break when the expression is true. Debug --> Add Watch

Comment: When you run it in SSMS are you logging in with the same Windows credentials Access is using to log in as the current domain user?

Comment: @MarkBalhoff yes.  I think the problem may be in the parameters... IDK if VBA likes the '0' as a parameter, although it did fine with the other storedproc I tested.  I read that you are really supposed to use Command objects for parametized queries.  Is this the issue?

Comment: I use Command objects when I do it so while I think the way you are doing it should work, I can't say for sure whether we can make it work without a Command object. Seems like it should but I don't think I've ever done it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the stored procedure is included in securables for the user you are accessing the database with. For this:

On your SSMS under security --> under users --> right click the user you are accessing --> Click Properties --> click on Securables tab and look at the list and make sure that stored procedure is included there. If not click "search" button --> check the "specific objects" radio --> click OK --> click "Object type" button on new popup --> Check Stored procedures checkbox --> click OK --> Make sure the stored procedure is listed and click OK --> Now after it is listed under securables --> Under Explicit tab look for "Excute" in Permission column --> Find the one that has "dbo" under Grantor Column and check the Grant checkbox and click OK.

This should solve the problem.

Comment: This looks great. But I don't see `dbo` in the Grantor column for the stored procedure I'm having a problem with. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

make sure your dataset is not in filtered. set your dataset's filter to false then close it, then use it. Or better use a clean dataset.

Answer (score 0):

does your stored procedure possible have a debug select in it?  Possibly you are selecting the value of some variable as a debug statement.   This would have the effect of returning two tables. your dataset will at the first one unless told otherwise.

Do this in SSMS and make sure it is returning what you think it is returning.

```
exec SP_storedprocedure 0
```

Also, to break down the problem, make 4 debug.print statements and see which one(s) break.

Considering your statment to @MarkBalhoff about column count being zero, the other possibility is that you simply forgot to return your results at the end of the query. Are you building a temp table?

the last (or close to last) statement in your sp should be

```
select * from #temp
```

similar to calculating the correct value in a function , then forgetting to return it.